# Commuting an $\int$ improper at its both ends and $\lim$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $f, g$ be continuous nonnegative functions defined and improperly-integrable on $(0, \infty)$ Furthermore, assume they satisfy
>   $$
> \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0 \wedge \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xg(x)=0.
> $$
>   Then prove that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_0^\infty f(x)g(nx)dx = 0.
> $$

I tried to swap $\lim$ and $\int$.  I know that if the improper integral and its integrand converge uniformly, they commute.  But I am at a loss as to how to prove this condition.

I would be grateful if you could help me in this regard.

Comment: Very interesting. It seems to me that the problem is trivial when $\int_0^\infty$ is replaced by $\int_0^M$ for a fixed $M>0$. The trouble is at infinity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to use a direct bound for looking at the integral over  $[1,\infty)$:

$\int_1^\infty f(x) ng(nx) dx \leq \int_n^\infty f(u/n) g(u) du = \int_n^\infty \frac{f(u/n)}{u} (u g(u)) du \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_n^\infty f(u/n) (ug(u)) du$

The latter inequality follows from the fact that in the integrand $u > n \geq 1$.
If you get here, then by assumption, for sufficiently large $n$,   $u(g(u))$ is small for $u > n$. See if you can finish from this angle.

---

Okay, there is a delicate procedure I have in mind which I will outline here: (Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given)

1. Use continuity of $f$ near $0$ , find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $|x| < \delta$.
2. Separate the integral to $\int_0^\delta$ and $\int_\delta^\infty$.
3. Bound $\int_0^\delta f(x) ng(nx) dx < \epsilon \int_0^\delta ng(nx) dx = \epsilon \int_0^{n\delta} g(u) du < \epsilon |g|_1$
4. For $\int_\delta^\infty$, use the procedure above to get a bound of the form $|f|_1 \epsilon$. (Now that $\delta$ is fixed, if $n$ is large enough $u g(u) < \epsilon$ for $u > \delta n$.

So the full bound is $\epsilon(|f|_1 + |g|_1)$, so now you can adjust a few parameters above to get it back to $\epsilon$ if you wish, though it suffices that you can bound by a quantity that is arbitrarily small, and hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: So $L^1([1,\infty)) \subset L^2([1,\infty))$?

Comment: no it is not true sorry

Comment: Indeed, the tricky part is on any $[M,\infty)$. I cannot use the limit assumption on $g$.]

Comment: I think the limit assumption on g is only needed for the conclusion of dominated convergence theorem, so just need a simple bound on the integrand by a single n independent function which is integrable. to do so, a change of variables is needed to get rid of the n outside

Comment: @Evan I would be most grateful if you could elaborate on the  solution, especially, on how to solve this without using Lebesgue integral. (which I do not know about).

Comment: @Pteromys   So for the integral on 1 to infinity, traditional methods will work (What I wrote is basically the answer, once you take out $u g(u)$ from the integral outside with its bound).  I am currently looking into the integral for [0,1], though it appears Siminore had something for that?